# How to find and show all the information in a text file

Tags: linux, shell, unix, terminal

i'm new in shell programing. I want a text file as my database like this

```
Booktitle
abcd
Author
abcd
Publisher
abcd
Year of publication
2009
```

How can i use any keyword and let the program find all the information of that book. For example: When i type `grep -i "abcd" books.txt`. The program will show:

```
Booktitle    Author    Publisher    Year of Publication
abcd         abcd      abcd           2009
```

Thank you guys so much!

Answer (score 0):

`grep` only gives you lines, not groups of lines. You might want to format the file differently. One way is to construct the lines by

id seporator tag seporator data

like so:

```
abcd --- Title --- abcd
abcd --- Author --- efgh
abcd --- Publisher --- ijkl
abcd --- Year --- 2015

mnop --- Title --- mnop
mnop --- Author --- qrst
mnop --- Publisher --- ijkl
mnop --- Year --- 2007
```

When you use the book title as your id `grep` will give you all the information of a book when you search with the title.

Comment: Thank you for your solution. But if i do that, the title will show up in all the information lines. Is there any other solution?

Comment: You don't have to have the title line. Of course one way would be to put it all in one line like so:
Title --- abcd ----- Author --- efgh ----- Publisher --- ijkl ----- Year --- 2015 (new line)
Title --- mnop ----- Author --- qrst ----- Publisher --- ijkl ----- Year --- 2007